# How to fix the errors in quickbooks API, GuzzleHttlp saying Request has invalid or Unsupported Property

Tags: php, laravel, payment, quickbooks

I was working on the Quickbooks API for one of my projects. I'm getting the following error:

GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException Client error: POST https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com//*Private Info */ resulted in a 400 Bad Request response: {"Fault":{"Error":[{"Message":"Request has invalid or unsupported property","Detail":"Property Name:Unrecognized field \ (truncated...)

The Code:

I have no idea what it is saying to me to fix it. Can anyone help me with this?

Please find the updated code

```
if(!$buyer->details->quickbooks_id){
            $customer = $http->post(
                // Sandbox API hidden for security reason
                [
                    'headers' => [
                        'Accept'=> 'application/json',
                        'Content-type'=> 'application/json',
                        'Authorization'=> 'Bearer '.$oauth['access_token']
                    ],
                    'body' => json_encode(
                        [
                        'PrimaryEmailAddr' => [
                            'Address' => $buyer->email
                        ],
                        'DisplayName' => $buyer->first_name.' '.$buyer->last_name.' - '.$buyer->details->business_name,
                        'PrimaryPhone'=>[
                            'FreeFormNumber'=> $buyer->phone
                        ],
                        'CompanyName'=>$buyer->details->business_name,
                        'GivenName'=>$buyer->first_name,
                        'FamilyName'=>$buyer->last_name,
                        'BillAddr'=> [
                            "CountrySubDivisionCode" => $buyer->details->state, 
                            "City" => $buyer->details->city, 
                            "PostalCode" => $buyer->details->zip, 
                            "Line1" => $buyer->details->address,
                            "Country" => $buyer->details->country
                        ]
                    ])
                ]
            );
            $customer = json_decode((string)$customer->getBody(), true);
            $buyer->details->quickbooks_id = $customer['Customer']['Id'];
            $buyer->details->save();
        }

        dd($buyer, $buyer->details, $buyer->details->quickbooks_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the issue is with the request body. I had the same issue with the data i pass.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32055228)